# how azure data lake client different from azure blob client

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I've encountered a situation were my code using the Azure data lake client has been replaced with a code using Azure blob client.

Are the any specific reasons to use one or the other ?
how are those 2 different from one another ?

Comment: I suggest starting with the docs for Azure Storage and Azure Data Lake, to learn about the differences (there are several). This is unfortunately off-topic here (it's really documentation-oriented, and also a bit opinion based as you're asking for reasons to use one vs the other)

Comment: well that's exactly why I'm asking the question - is for arguments and reasons to use one vs another. Hoping somebody has already done the work of parsing all the docs and may have the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are the any specific reasons to use one or the other ? how are those 2
> different from one another ?

Even though Data Lake Storage is built on top of Azure Blob Storage, there are certain features which are specific to Data Lake Storage only (e.g. concept of File Systems, granular ACLs etc.).

If you are working with the features only available in Data Lake Storage, you would need to use the SDK targeting Data Lake Storage (e.g. [`Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake)). For the blob storage related features available in your Data Lake Storage, you can use the SDK targeting Blob Storage (e.g. [`Azure.Storage.Blobs`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs)).

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. Do You happen to know any specific "features available" on the DFS storage exclusively that are not available on BLobs?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=difference+between+azure+blob+storage+and+azure+data+lake+gen2&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 

Comment: The answer is: https://www.smikar.com/what-is-the-difference-between-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-and-blob-storage/ 
Thanks @Mantri. Didn't find anything useful the first time. But now I see this nice article answering my question exactly.